# invoke multiple projects from a single solution Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

OK, I'm going to try this question again because there seemed to be alot of confusion from people before.

To give an example of my issue. I have one project that is named "MBSA", and Another project that is named "Administrative Account".

So "MBSA" runs first and is a windows form that asks the user if they want the MBSA tool downloaded and installed.

After the answer is given on "MBSA" I want that answer to output to my INI file which i've done and then move on to opening "Administrative Account" (which is a console collecting information).

I can not get this to happen from the "MBSA" Project.

I can add the reference but have not been able to add it to the "using statements" or the body of code as a final step in "MBSA"

I've tried be as descriptive as possible with this question hopefully I have covered all the pertinent points. any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a reference in the MBSA project to your AdministrativeAccount project?  Do you also have an entry point in MBSA?  A class that checks if MBSA is installed, if so do AdminAccount.xyz, else install MBSA then do AdminAccount.xyz?

Comment: Firstly, I appreciate the fast response on this issue. when you say entry point are you talking about the line "'Administrator Account' Admin = new 'Administrator Account'"? If so then yes, I have tried this and it doesn't recognize the "administrator Account" as something usable and redlines it. im not at my work terminal so I can't give you the specific error currently but will be more than happy to provide it tomorrow morning.